# Is there any easy way to calculate the value of this determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 10! & e^{-7}\\ 
1 & 2 & -1 & 2 & \sqrt{2} & 2 \\ 
-1 & -2 & 3 & -3 & 1 & -\frac{1}{5} \\ 
-2 & -1 & 3 & 2 & -2 & -9 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix}

I still can't see any easy way to compute the determinant above I would appreciate any kind of help. Thanks.

Comment: A tip to compute determinants is to pick the row with the most zeros. But the problem is still tedious. I would recommend giving it to Mathematica.

Comment: If you expand the last two rows it is $2$ times the determinant of the upper left $4 \times 4$.  You can replace the upper four rows in the last two columns with $0$s to save typing.  I don't see an easy way to simplify the upper left $4 \times 4$.

Comment: As a quick observation, it is clear that the absurd values like $10!$ and $e^{-7}$ and so on in the top-right corner have absolutely no relevance to the determinant whatsover.  This can be seen from the definition and noting that the only patterns with a nonzero product will be those which utilize the $4,1$ in the bottom right or the $2,1$ in the bottom right.  Beyond that, you can save a bit of time with what you know about block matrices and their determinants and treat this like a block matrix thanks to the large block of zeroes in the bottom left.

Comment: Also, you can add multiples of a column to another (same with rows) and the determinant won't change. You can use this in order to get a more sparse matrix.

Comment: Those entries $10!, e^{-7},\sqrt{2},-1/5$ are red herrings.  As @maxbp noted, they do not effect the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that you can add a multiple of a row / column to another row / column, and it does not change the determinant. Then use the fact that some rows are similar. For instance, do the following operations in order:

- $R_5 \leftarrow R_5 - 4 R_6$
- $R_3 \leftarrow R_3 + R_2$
- $R_4 \leftarrow R_4 + 2 R_2$
- $R_4 \leftarrow R_4 - R_1$

Then flip $R_6$ and $R_5$, $R_1$ and $R_2$ (each operation multiplies the determinant by $-1$, so it remains unchanged), and you get a triangular matrix with diagonal $(1, 3, 2, 4, 1, -2)$, so you have a determinant of $- 48$.